# what's wakeups_resource.ips and is it indicate a crash?

Tags: ios, crash, ips

As this problem said:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110446?login=true,
it's a crash or some kind of warning or metric log?
ips file get from: iOS Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > Analytics Data, generate by running monkey